# sqlite3.OperationalError: attempt to write a readonly database even when I change the permissions

Tags: python, sql, linux, database, sqlite

I found this question multiple times and none of the answers solved my problem so I had to ask it again.

For some context, I encountered this error in a 3D reconstruction project. I'm using COLMAP for 3D reconstruction and it uses sqlite3 internally. I have to manipulate the database in order to improve my results but I can't write anything to it.

This is how I'm doing it now.

- Create a directory for reconstruction and change its permissions
- Create database connection, change its permissions and create tables
- Insert records manually (this is where I get `sqlite3.OperationalError: attempt to write a readonly database`)

  ```
            os.chmod(reconstruction_directory, 0o777)
            database_path = reconstruction_directory / 'database.db'
            colmap_database = database_utilities.COLMAPDatabase.connect(database_path)
            os.chmod(database_path, 0o777)
            colmap_database.create_tables()
  ```

I add records by simply running this method in `COLMAPDatabase` class.

```
def add_camera(self, camera_id, model, width, height, params, prior_focal_length):

    cursor = self.execute(
        'INSERT INTO cameras VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)',
        (
            camera_id,
            model,
            width,
            height,
            array_to_blob(params),
            prior_focal_length
        )
    )

    return cursor.lastrowid
```

Environment:

- Python 3.9.16
- Ubuntu 22.04
- COLMAP and sqlite3 (probably latest versions)

Edit: I can only write records when I use `mode=memory` in the uri. `rw` or `rwc` raises the same `sqlite3.OperationalError: attempt to write a readonly database` error for some reason.